# Why do I get memory corruption in this code?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I wrote code that duplicates a `char**`. But it doesn't work. Based on what I've seen in the debugger, `malloc()` can not allocate memory for a variable that is named `ret`. But I think everything is okay.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
int map_y_len(char **map)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(map[i] != NULL)
        i++;
    return i;
}

char **copy_matrix(char **map)
{
    char **ret;
    int len;
    int i;

    len = map_y_len(map);
    ret = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (len + 1));
    i = 0;
    while (map[i] != NULL)
    {
        ret[i] = strdup(map[i]);
        i++;
    }
    ret[i] = NULL;
    return (ret);
}
```

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue using the hardcoded data you are using for testing?

Comment: Maybe your array of null-terminated strings is not defined correctly. How are you sure the error is in the code you posted?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have presented, assuming that map is a NULL-terminated array of pointers to nul-terminated strings. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ - tell us more! _"malloc() can not allocate memory for a variable that is named ret"_ - clearly not true, how did you arrive at that conclusion? Are you saying that if you rename that variable it magically works?!  Describe your debugger observation, rather than your flawed diagnosis.